# How to import your own package?

Tags: go, package

After reading https://golang.org/doc/code.html, and having a look at a few StackOverflow questions on the topic, **I still can't build a program with several files in it**.

My GOPATH is: `C:/go_dev/`, and my directory structure is:

```
go_dev/
    src/
        github.com/
            aurelienCastel/
                crashTest/
                    main.go
                    parser/
                        parser.go
```

**main.go:**

```
package main

import "github.com/aurelienCastel/crashTest/parser"

func main() {
     info := parser.get_info_from("file.go")
     // ...
}
```

**parser/parser.go:**

```
package parser

// ...

func get_info_from(file_name string) Info {
    // ...
}
```

When I run `go install`in the `crashTest`directory I get the following error:

> undefined: parser.get_info_from

I know this is a recurrent question, but could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `get_info_from` is not exported; rename it to `GetInfoFrom`.

Comment: You mean there is a naming convention to make function private/public, like snake_case for private and CamelCase for public? I didn't saw this in the specs...

Comment: See [Exported identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers). The uppercase first letter makes it exported; [using camel case over snake case is just convention](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#mixed-caps).

Comment: Thanks, if you want post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: While not very prominent in the spec, the Tour of Go explains this very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for an identifier to be accessible from an outside package, its name must begin with an uppercase letter. [From the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers):

> #### Exported identifiers
>
> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> - the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case letter (Unicode class "Lu"); and
> - the identifier is declared in the package block or it is a field name or method name.
>
> All other identifiers are not exported.

Additionally, [it is Go convention](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#mixed-caps) to name identifiers using mixed case, rather than snake case.

```
package parser

// ...

func GetInfoFrom(filename string) Info {
    // ...
}
```